# SweetAlert2-react Cancel Button does not work

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2

I'm trying to confirm a user delete using Sweetalert2 in react, but when I use the 'Cancel' button, it still sends the form to delete the user, as if I've pressed 'Confirm'. Here's my code

```
export default function Users() {

const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
const [isModalOpen, setModal] = useState(false)
const [hover, setHover] = useState('')
const [userModal, setuserModal] = useState('')
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
const [userDelete, setUserDelete] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${OC_API}/users`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        setUsers(res)
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(`Hubo un error Cod. 200 ${e}`))
},[])

function toggleModal(user) {
    setuserModal(user)
    setModal(!isModalOpen)
}

function handleDeleteUser(user) {
    fetch(`${OC_API}/userdelete`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({"user_id": user._id})
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.ok){
            alert('¡Usuario eliminado!')
        } else {
            alert('¡Hubo un error! Cod. 201')
        }
    }).then(() => {
        fetch(`${OC_API}/users`)
        .then(res => res.json(),
            error =>  {alert(`Error de conexión ${error.message}`); throw error;})
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            setUsers(data)
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(`Hubo un error Cod. 202 ${e}`))
    })
}

if (users == undefined || users == [] || users == null ){
  return (
    <Loading />
  )
} else {
    return(
        <div className="container">
                <motion.div className="row justify-content-center" 
                    initial={{ opacity: 0 }} 
                    animate={{ opacity: 1}} 
                    transition={{ duration: 1}}
                    style={{'paddingTop':'3em'}}
                >
                <div className="col col-md-12 text-right" >
                    <AddUserButton />
                </div>
                <div className="col col-md-12 text-center" >
                    <ParagraphStyle>
                        <div className="card" >
                            <div className="card-header text-left">
                                Administrar Usuarios
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <div className="table-responsive">
                                    <AdminTableStyle>
                                        <table className="table">
                                            <thead >
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">RUT</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Correo</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Rol</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                {users.map(user => (
                                                    <Fragment key={user.id}>
                                                    <SweetAlert
                                                        show={show}
                                                        icon={'warning'}
                                                        title="Eliminar Usuario"
                                                        text={`¿Desea borrar a usuario ${userDelete.name}?`}
                                                        showCancelButton={true}
                                                        confirmButtonColor={'#3085d6'}
                                                        cancelButtonColor={'#d33'}
                                                        cancelButtonText={'Cancelar'}
                                                        confirmButtonText={'Confirmar'}
                                                        onCancel={ () => {setShow(false)
                                                        return }}
                                                        onConfirm={() => {
                                                            handleDeleteUser(userDelete)
                                                            setShow(false)
                                                        }}
                                                    />
                                                    <tr onMouseOver={() => setHover(user._id)} onMouseLeave={() => setHover('')}>
                                                        <td style={{'textAlign': 'left'}}>{user.name}</td>
                                                        <td>{user.rut}</td>
                                                        <td>{user.email}</td>
                                                        <td>{user.role}</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <span style={{'marginRight': '5px'}}>
                                                            {
                                                                hover==user._id?
                                                                <a href="#" onClick={() => toggleModal(user)}>
                                                                    <FontAwesomeIcon 
                                                                        icon='edit'
                                                                    />
                                                                </a>
                                                                :
                                                                    ''
                                                            }
                                                            </span>
                                                            <span>
                                                            {
                                                                hover==user._id?
                                                                <a href="#" onClick={() => {
                                                                    setUserDelete(user)
                                                                    setShow(true)
                                                                }}

                                                                >
                                                                    <FontAwesomeIcon 
                                                                        icon='trash'
                                                                    />
                                                                </a>
                                                                :
                                                                    ''
                                                            }
                                                            </span>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </Fragment>
                                                ))}
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </AdminTableStyle>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ParagraphStyle>
                </div>
            </motion.div>
            <UserEdit 
                setuserModal={setuserModal}
                isModalOpen={isModalOpen}
                userModal={userModal}
                toggleModal={toggleModal}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

I tried adding an `onCancel` option in the Sweetalert component and set the `Show` state to false, but it continues executing the `handleDeleteUser` function
Any suggestions?

Comment: can you add a `console.trace('something')` call to the top of your handle delete function and see the source of it?

Comment: @Tom it outputs ```console.trace() something users.js:38
    handleDeleteUser users.js:38
    onConfirm users.js:116
    React 2
        value
        value```  But I cannot see what to make of that

Comment: Is like the Cancel button and the Confirm button both works as "confirm" command, and I cannot make the Cancel button exit the opened modal, instead of calling ```HandleDeleteUser()```